# How can we encrypt a specific file/folder in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, encryption, android-security

I am creating a file inside android root data,

```
    File myDir;
    myDir = new File(cw.getDir("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath() + File.separator + "New_Folder");

    if (!myDir.exists())
    {
        myDir.mkdirs();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("ASA9", "File Already Created.");
    }
```

Can i encrypt that file?

Or can i Put a password to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the android's official documentation to do this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedFile

```
  String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);

  File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "secret_data");
  EncryptedFile encryptedFile = EncryptedFile.Builder(
      file,
      context,
      masterKeyAlias,
      EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
  ).build();

  // write to the encrypted file
  FileOutputStream encryptedOutputStream = encryptedFile.openFileOutput();

  // read the encrypted file
  FileInputStream encryptedInputStream = encryptedFile.openFileInput();
```

You also have to add this dependency in the android build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc02"
}
```

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged, or at least they used to be. However, this is one of those cases where the URL itself *is* the summary. Unfortunately, the android keystore does not support keys derived from passwords.

Comment: I understand, but the question wasn't specifically about using a password, as rather encrypting the file

Comment: I understand, I wasn't criticizing.

Comment: I am not able to use EncryptedFile or MasterKeys, do i have to import or implement something else at start? @CyberGh

Comment: Yes, you have to add a dependency, I've updated my answer.